How to negate exit code for `git bisect run`?
I want to use bisect for the first commit that introduced some line. Using git log -S wasn't successful, so I suspect the issue be introduced in a merge commit.
I could do git bisect run ag my-search-phrase if I were looking for the first commit to remove that line. I tried to use ! ag, but git does not find executable !. I could do bash -c "..." but this is clumsy and harder to read.
Is there a more elegant way to negate the exit code so git bisect run can make use of that?

I forgot about the difference of git log -S and git log -G. The latter shows every match, the former only if the count of the search term changes. Using git log -G finds the commit. Anyhow, the question remains.

would using a generic not wrapper script count ? a quick (and untested) 2 liner: "$@"; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi

I'd have to write a script then. I do occasionally for complex issues, but I am looking for an elegant solution here.

I meant: you can have this notscript present on your path (for example: in $HOME/bin) and use it anywhere. It would just be a scripted way to do not rather than relying on the special char ! and shell builtin. But you are right: my suggestion is to have some form of a custom script.

! is defined by POSIX and should be available in all compliant shells, cf. 2.9.2 Pipelines, Exit Status

If the pipeline does not begin with the ! reserved word, the exit status shall be the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline. Otherwise, the exit status shall be the logical NOT of the exit status of the last command. That is, if the last command returns zero, the exit status shall be 1; if the last command returns greater than zero, the exit status shall be zero.

That means it should be easy enough to write a trivial wrapper script:
$ cat "$HOME/bin/not"
#!/bin/sh
! "$@"
$

(maybe it's possible to combine it with exec?)
Then use:
git bisect run not ag my-search-phrase

The only problem with this approach is that it turns the special exit code 125 (used by git bisect to "skip" the current commit) into 0 as well. If you need special handling of this exit code, your script becomes minimally longer to ignore exit code 125:
#!/bin/sh
"$@"
case "$?" in
  125) exit 125 ;;
  0) exit 1 ;;
  *) exit 0 ;;
esac


Couldn't combine it with exec, the shell needs to wait for the child to collect its exit status in order to exit with the inverted version of that status.

@CharlesDuffy yeah, that's what I was afraid

Yes, I think defining this helper will be the best option.
